# Music symbols in unicode on android

Tags: android, unicode

We want to draw a music symbols in View.onDraw(),and found that unicode contains a few of symbols.[here is the Code Chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf)
  But when i call drawText("\u1D100"),only the four character after u encoded,the last "0" still draw with "0".How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Java/Android are encoded using UTF-16.  The `\u` escape notation supports up to 4 hex digits. So, to encode a Unicode codepoint above U+FFFF, you have to encode it as a UTF-16 surrogate pair. This is clearly explained in the Java/Android documentations.

`U+1D100` is `0xD834 0xDD00` in UTF-16, so use this instead:

```
drawText("\uD834\uDD00", ...)
```

Alternatively, you can convert the Unicode codepoint to a `char[]` array at runtime and then draw it:

```
char[] ch = Character.toChars(0x1D100);
drawText(ch, 0, ch.length, ...)
```

Either way, of course you have to use a font that actually supports `U+1D100`.